# is there anyway to have just right or just left horizontal space using ckeditor

Tags: html, image, ckeditor, margin

I am using ckeditor and I have a number of pictures in my content.  One issue i see is that you have the ability to add horizontal or vertical space around a picture but you can't just set a right or just a left horizontal picture.  Normally if I have a picture on the left side of a page and the content to the right, I would just want to set the right margin (to avoid the image being indented on the left)

from looking at [the ckeditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo), I only see the ability to set the space on both sides of the picture.  Is there anyway around this without having to do custom css as I want to give this feature for non technical users?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this uses custom css, but its in the ckeditor ui; right click on the image, click on the advanced option tab; change the margins to fit your needs. flushed left, margin-left:0; flushed right will be margin-right:0

Comment: thanks, i was hoping there was a way to do this without custom css but if this is the answer than so be it.

Answer (score -1):

When we right click image in ckeditor demo, It is showing one option as *image properties*. When we click on this a model window will popup. This model window has alignment property. One can set it to left or right as required.

[image: Right Click on image]

[image: model window for image properties]

[image: image on right side]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.  I know i can align left or right but i want to control spacing for just left or right (not both)

Comment: Sorry for miss interpreting the question. You can adjust left/right spacing by going to **advance setting tab** in **image properties modal window** and add style accordingly. Like setting `left-margin:5px; right-margin:15px;`

Answer (score -1):

What if we put 0 in hspace and 0 in vspace and adjust alignment = left|right.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. I know i can align left or right but i want to control spacing for just left or right (not both)